# Magento 2 - How to override Admin Gallery.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I am trying to override admin file,

`module-product-video\view\adminhtml\templates\helper\gallery.phtml`

I am not able to find layout file for this because it set inside the block called,

`magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php`

Can anyone guide me?

**Updated code:**

`etc/di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content" type="Bhupendra\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\Content" />
```

**BLOCK:**

```
<?php

namespace Bhupendra\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Content extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Bhupendra_Helloworld::product/gallery.phtml';
}
```

**Template:**

```
module-product-video\view\adminhtml\templates\helper\gallery.phtml
```

to

```
view\adminhtml\templates\product\gallery.phtml
```

Comment: `view\product\gallery.phtml` => `view\adminhtml\templates\product\gallery.phtml`. We also need to have a prefix module in the variable template: `protected $_template = 'Bhupendra_Helloworld::product/gallery.phtml';`

Comment: Yes! i have already done these both but still it is not working my path is \view\adminhtml\templates\product

Comment: You have a prefix `protected $_template = 'Bhupendra_Helloworld::product/gallery.phtml';` ? Please, update your question properly.

Comment: Now! i think this block is not override the this template because even i am changing from that particular core block it is not changing the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take a look: `vendor/magento/module-product-video/Observer/ChangeTemplateObserver.php`. We can see that this template will be added via Observer event. So, we need to disable this observer event in our module. And then, try to add our custom template.

*Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml*

```
<event name="catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout">
        <observer name="change_template" disabled="true"/>
        <observer name="custom_change_template" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" />
</event>
```

*Vendor/Module/Observer/ChangeTemplateObserver.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeTemplateObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
     $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::helper/gallery.phtml');
   }
}
```

Comment: how can we add js file on that page in header

Comment: Seem that you're asking a new issue, please open new question.

Comment: Gallery.phtml is not calling from my module

Comment: Uppercase or lowercase your template name? `Gallery.phtml` or `gallery.phtml`? It should be lowercase.

Comment: yes i am using lowercase template name but still is not working i had flushed the cache .

Comment: You should update your question with your custom code lines.

Comment: I have already updated code

Comment: I have just took a look on your updated question. Please, read my answer carefully. Seem that your template file is wrong the path.

Comment: I have just given custom path rather that follow exact directory structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45088/discussion-between-bhupendra-jadeja-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: Thanks , it's worked for Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a module.

> app/code/Test/Video/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Video" setup_version="2.0.0" schema_version="2.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        <module name="Magento_Store"/>
        <module name="Magento_Ui"/>
    </sequence>
</config>
```

> app/code/Test/Video/registration.php

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Video',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Test/Video/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout">
        <observer name="change_template" disabled="true"/>
        <observer name="custom_change_template" instance="Test\Video\Observer\OptionObserver" />
    </event> 
</config>
```

> app/code/Test/Video/Observer/ChangeTemplateObserver.php

```
 <?php

namespace Test\Video\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OptionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
     $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('Test_Video::helper/gallery.phtml');
   }
}
```

> app/code/Test/Video/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content */
$elementName = $block->getElement()->getName() . '[images]';
$formName = $block->getFormName();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="add-video-button-container">
        <button id="add_video_button"
                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Video'));?>"
                data-role="add-video-button"
                type="button"
                class="action-secondary"
                data-ui-id="widget-button-1">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Video')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    **<div class="uplload" style="color:#000; font-weight:bold";>Please Upload a Image 1000px * 1000px </div>** - **If you wanna add a text , you can do like this** 
</div>

<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content */
$element = $block->getElement();
$elementToggleCode = $element->getToggleCode() ? $element->getToggleCode() : 'toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)';
?>

<div id="<?php echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>"
     class="gallery"
     data-mage-init='{"openVideoModal":{}}'
     data-parent-component="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getData('config/parentComponent')) ?>"
     data-images="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getImagesJson()) ?>"
     data-types="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
         $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($block->getImageTypes())
     ) ?>"
>

    <?php
    if (!$block->getElement()->getReadonly()):
        ?>
        <div class="image image-placeholder">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUploaderHtml();
            ?>
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <p class="image-placeholder-text">
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        __('Browse to find or drag image here')
                    ); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml('additional_buttons'); ?>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData):
        ?>
        <input name="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($typeData['name']) ?>"
               data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
               class="image-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($typeData['code']) ?>"
               type="hidden"
               value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($typeData['value']) ?>"/>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
    <script id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>-template" data-template="image" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <div class="image item <% if (data.disabled == 1) { %>hidden-for-front<% } %>  <% if (data.video_url) { %>video-item<% } %>"
             data-role="image">
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][position]"
                   value="<%- data.position %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
                   class="position"/>
            <% if (data.media_type !== 'external-video') {%>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][media_type]"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
                   value="image"/>
            <% } else { %>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][media_type]"
                   value="<%- data.media_type %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <% } %>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][video_provider]"
                   value="<%- data.video_provider %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][file]"
                   value="<%- data.file %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][value_id]"
                   value="<%- data.value_id %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][label]"
                   value="<%- data.label %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][disabled]"
                   value="<%- data.disabled %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][removed]"
                   value="" class="is-removed"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][video_url]"
                   value="<%- data.video_url %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][video_title]"
                   value="<%- data.video_title %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][video_description]"
                   value="<%- data.video_description %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][video_metadata]"
                   value="<%- data.video_metadata %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][role]"
                   value="<%- data.video_description %>"
                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"/>

            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <img class="product-image"
                     data-role="image-element"
                     src="<%- data.url %>"
                     alt="<%- data.label %>"/>

                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="action-remove"
                            data-role="delete-button"
                            title="<% if (data.media_type == 'external-video') {%>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                __('Delete video')
                            ); ?>
                        <%} else {%>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                __('Delete image')
                            ); ?>
                        <%}%>">
                    <span>
                        <% if (data.media_type == 'external-video') { %>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                            __('Delete video')
                        ); ?>
                        <% } else {%>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                            __('Delete image')
                        ); ?>
                        <%} %>
                    </span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="draggable-handle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-fade"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                            __('Hidden')
                        ); ?></span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-description">
                <% if (data.media_type !== 'external-video') {%>
                <div class="item-title" data-role="img-title"><%- data.label %></div>
                <div class="item-size">
                    <span data-role="image-dimens"></span>, <span data-role="image-size"><%- data.sizeLabel %></span>
                </div>
                <% } else { %>
                <div class="item-title" data-role="img-title"><%- data.video_title %></div>
                <% } %>
            </div>

            <ul class="item-roles" data-role="roles-labels">
                <?php
                foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData):
                    ?>
                    <li data-role-code="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        $typeData['code']
                    ) ?>" class="item-role item-role-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        $typeData['code']
                    ) ?>">
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($typeData['label']) ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script data-role="img-dialog-container-tmpl" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <div class="image-panel" data-role="dialog">
        </div>
    </script>

    <script data-role="img-dialog-tmpl" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <div class="image-panel-preview">
            <img src="<%- data.url %>" alt="<%- data.label %>" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-panel-controls">
            <strong class="image-name"><%- data.label %></strong>

            <fieldset class="admin__fieldset fieldset-image-panel">
                <div class="admin__field field-image-description">
                    <label class="admin__field-label" for="image-description">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Alt Text')?></span>
                    </label>

                    <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <textarea data-role="image-description"
                                      rows="3"
                                      class="admin__control-textarea"
                                      name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                      echo $elementName
                                      ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][label]"><%- data.label %></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="admin__field field-image-role">
                    <label class="admin__field-label">
                            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                    __('Role')
                                ); ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="admin__field-control">
                        <ul class="multiselect-alt">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($block->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) :
                                ?>
                                <li class="item">
                                    <label>
                                        <input class="image-type"
                                               data-role="type-selector"
                                               data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
                                               type="checkbox"
                                               value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                                   $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                                               ) ?>"
                                        />
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                            $attribute->getFrontendLabel()
                                        ) ?>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <?php
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="admin__field admin__field-inline field-image-size" data-role="size">
                    <label class="admin__field-label">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Image Size') ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="admin__field-value" data-message="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('{size}') ?>"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="admin__field admin__field-inline field-image-resolution" data-role="resolution">
                    <label class="admin__field-label">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Image Resolution') ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="admin__field-value" data-message="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('{width}^{height} px') ?>"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="admin__field field-image-hide">
                    <div class="admin__field-control">
                        <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   id="hide-from-product-page"
                                   data-role="visibility-trigger"
                                   data-form-part="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $formName ?>"
                                   value="1"
                                   class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                   name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][disabled]"
                            <% if (data.disabled == 1) { %>checked="checked"<% } %> />

                            <label for="hide-from-product-page" class="admin__field-label">
                                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                    __('Hide from Product Page')
                                ); ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </script>
    <div id="<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getNewVideoBlockName();?>" style="display:none">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormHtml();?>
        <div id="video-player-preview-location" class="video-player-sidebar">
            <div class="video-player-container"></div>
            <div class="video-information title">
                <label><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        __('Title:')
                    ); ?> </label><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="video-information uploaded">
                <label><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        __('Uploaded:')
                    ); ?> </label><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="video-information uploader">
                <label><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        __('Uploader:')
                    ); ?> </label><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="video-information duration">
                <label><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        __('Duration:')
                    ); ?> </label><span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('new-video'); ?>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery('body').trigger('contentUpdated');
</script>
```

Follow this one. you will get.

Comment: Why do you have to create a module? How do you create it? What should be the content? Your answer is very limited...

Comment: Can you please  tell me , without creating a module , how you can override this .

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need to create a module. I mean that your answer is not very helpful if you do not explain why, where, what and how

Comment: Thanks Rama Chandran M - I don't know how to do edit above code. Reallly Thanks.